# .Net Core Web API Post route endpoint not being hit

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-web-api-routing, webapi

I have the following .Net Core API route defined.

```
[HttpPost("/addproduct")]
[Consumes("application/json")]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<ProductDTO>> AddProduct([FromBody] ProductDTO){}
```

I already have the following attributes defined on the class:

```
[EnableCors()]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
```

I am calling it like this: `https://localhost:xxxxx/api/products/addproduct` and I'm passing a payload to it that represents the productDTO.  Why does this route not get hit?

Comment: Use `[HttpPost("addproduct")]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the routing attribute used on the HttpPost.

As defined above, the AddProduct action method matches the following url:

```
https://localhost:xxxx/addproduct
```

Even though you're using token replacement for the controller name,by using a leading slash you're overriding that route on the AddProduct method.

To properly route to the method remove the leading slash like this:

```
    [HttpPost("addproduct")]
    [Consumes("application/json")]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<ProductDTO>> AddProduct([FromBody] ProductDTO productDto)
```

For more information regarding attribute routing or controller routing in general [read this page on Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1)